# Android Maps and GUI

Tags: android, google-maps, onclick

i am creating an android application which includes maps. I have finished the maps but for the reason that I am new to android programming I would like to ask how to create lets say a menu and when a button is clicked like the map button,then the map would be displayed. For the code that I have got now when i run the application the emulator shows the map,but what do i need to do in order to display a menu first instead of the map.For instance to display some options and when the map button is clicked then the map is shown up. Please help, anyone could give me some advice ?? thank you

Comment: Once look at this http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/01/options-menu-example-in-android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to override onCreateOptionsMenu like:

```
@Override  
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);  
        return true;  
    }
```

then you need to override onOptionsItemSelected like:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.map:
        // write logic here for open map
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourMapActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    return true;
}
```

And XML file is main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:title="Map"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: where should the menu.xml file should be listed ? under the menu folder or the layout folder ? thanks

Comment: hmm I am trying to work it out but couldn't do it the way you told me as I can understand that it is right. What I am trying to do now is adding a button and hide the map in there so when the button is clicked then the map gets displayed. Thank you in advance my friend. I will come back to you if I manage to do it. On the menu folder under res I have only one file called main.xml

Comment: Still cant do it the button is created and when i click it does what i want but the button is created on the map so when i run the app the map is displayed and the button is displayed over the map :(

Comment: public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 GoogleMap gMap;
 private final LatLng LOCATION_Chicago=new LatLng(xnumber,ynumber);
 
 public void OnClick_Chicago(View x)

 {
  CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_Chicago,13);
  gMap.animateCamera(update);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  gMap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
  
 }
}

Comment: sorry that file name is main.xml only, I edited my answer see above

Comment: yes thank you but if i do what u suggest to me it stills shows me the map when i run the application. I suppose there is something to do with the fragment and not with the menu i have posted some of my code above could you please suggest anything to me ? I appriciate your help.

Comment: you can take one activity as a welcome page when you click on the menu ,then you should able to see map in another activity...

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try the example source code for Sliding Menu for Android.

Please try and let me know. Thanks

[Sliding Menu for Android](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)